# How to use an !if in Condition element of Policy while creating cross account IAM role in AWS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am creating a cross account access role in aws. In my yml template I need to have an if condition inside the Condition element of the Policy. Have tried various things to make it work. But getting errors like ill formed yaml and E0000 could not find expected ':'
The yaml is currently like this:

```
Condition:
              StringEquals:
                aws:pqrs: !Ref pqrs
            - !If
              - HasRoleArn
              - Condition:
                  StringEquals:
                    aws:pqrs: !Ref pqrs
                  StringLike:
                    aws:RequestTag/abcd/principal: "*"
                  'Null':
                    aws:RequestTag/abcd/principal: "false"
              - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

earlier it was like this(when it was working before adding the If condition in Condition Element:

```
Condition:
              StringEquals:
                aws:pqrs: !Ref pqrs
```

Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You **can't use** `Fn::If` in `Conditions` . `Fn::If` can only be [used in](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if):

> Currently, CloudFormation supports the Fn::If intrinsic function in the metadata attribute, update policy attribute, and property values in the **Resources section and Outputs** sections of a template.

You would have to create a custom [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) to support such a functionality.

Comment: Can we use is under AssumeRolePolicyDocument inside IAM Role though? We already use it with Effect inside the AssumeRolePolicyDocument, so should be able to use inside Condition element aswell I believe.

Comment: @shivampandita What role? Which `AssumeRolePolicyDocument`? You question is different and does not ask about these things.

Comment: I needed to specify If condition in the Condition element of the IAM Role (which we specify inside Assume3RolePolicyDocument). Solved it by moving the If condition outside(made IF condition on statement  level instead of having it inside Condition element) and it worked! When I say Condition here , it means condition similar to specified in this doc.[link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_iam-condition-keys.html)